# Change the default number of rows displayed in data table

Tags: jquery, datatables

i am using  jquery.dataTables.min.js **Version:1.9.2**. I have referred so many examples in web and **stack overflow** too. But i didn't get working.

this is what i have tried yet.

```
$('.invoSumryTB').dataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bRetrieve": true,  
});
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html

Comment: I need to load 100 record on page load.

Comment: Then change `iDisplayLength` to 100...? Also, is there a reason you're creating the datatable, then immediately destroying it?

Comment: i just post a sample in my code **"iDisplayLength": 50,** is also not working. it is not showing 50 records, It is only displaying 10 rows

Comment: if i not calling the destroy it gives a error alert, it says datatable could not be reinitialize

Comment: sorry with out  `$(".invoSumryTB").dataTable().fnDestroy();` line also it is only displays only 10 rows. and no error alerts.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code - here is a 1.9.2 example with your settings, it works right away -> **http://jsfiddle.net/92d2pfko/**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery DataTables Pagination Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051302/jquery-datatables-pagination-size)

Comment: Does the data your passing to your datatable have 10 values by any chance?