# Change values of select box of “show 10 entries” of jquery datatable

Tags: datatable

Is it posible to decrease the show entries in datatable. I want to only show 5 entries instead of 10.

Comment: you need to show some code in order to get some help on how to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery DataTables Pagination Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051302/jquery-datatables-pagination-size)

Answer (score 0):

change the iDisplayLength. This for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#tbl_id').dataTable({
    "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, -1], [25, 50, 75, "All"]],
    "iDisplayLength": 5
});
} );
```